# Cover background looping video not working on HTML

Tags: html

I tried making a looping background video but only the video controls are being displayed on the page, the rest is blank.

```
<section id="portfolio-cover" data-height="fullscreen">
   <div>
     <video id="background-video" playsinline autoplay muted loop width="320" height="240" opacity= 50 controls >
       <source src="chicago.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: is the video URL local or remote?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that the src is not being called correctly, is the file in the same folder as your html file? Or is it a link? Because I tested this out with a video link and a proper file path to the video and it works perfectly fine. Try double checking the path of your video file or if its a link, comment it here, so I can show you how to write it down in `src=""`

Comment: The video file is in the same folder as my html file. For some reason it only displays the controls and audio of the video but not the video itself. I also checked to see if I have a separate background color but I've got nothing.

Comment: This might be a problem with your IDE itself, or the way your file is being hosted on the web. What IDE are you using? And what are you using to host your files? (ie. locahost)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>videobg</title>
    <style>
    .mainblock{width:100%; float:left; margin:0 auto; padding:0; height:100vh; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
.mainblock #video-background{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width:100%; 
}
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
    .mainblock #video-background{width:auto; height:100vh;}
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mainblock">
        <video preload="metadata" id="video-background" controls="" autoplay="" loop="" playsinline="" muted="">
          <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Full screen Video tag html